Is there a known format for SPEC-OBJECT identifiers in RIF/ReqIF files?
Requirements (and other RE artefacts) are transferred from one RE tool (e.g. DOORS) to another (e.g. MKS) by means of RIF file format. Each item has an unique Identifier like
<SPEC-OBJECT IDENTIFIER="_46723631-afae-41fe-8b16-6a9079f5f08c" 
    LAST-CHANGE="2024-02-05T09:30:00">

Is there a known algorithm to produce such an identifier?
PS: I compared 2 tools and although numbers are differend both followed the _11111111-2222-3333-4444-5555555555555 pattern.

Well, officially, there's no rule. RIF 1.2 format defines the datatype  SPEC-OBJECT/IDENTIFIER as xs:ID, which according to W3C XML Schema definition is just NCName, which is more or less any string that does not begin with -, . or [0-9]. Inofficially, the formats that you mentioned look like ordinary UUIDS in the typical 8-4-4-4-12 format. There are many tools to generate UUIDs, e.g. Online UUID Generator
